# Singleton bean with ThreadLocal variable bahavior

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a bean with default singleton scope. This bean is access by many threads and I want student object to be specific to each thread. I am using spring boot with rest

In such implementation, how does singleton bean handles student objects set by different threads. Does spring return same A object to each thread but with customize object value for student variable?

```
@Service
class A{

 private InheritableThreadLocal<Student> student;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring will create only one instance object of the `class A` (let's call it `objA`) and within that object, the thread local variable will reside. Note that, Spring doesn't return the objA to any thread, but the threads executes the logic within or associated with `objA`.

However, the Threadlocal variable value is only visible to the thread which is executing the logic. In this case even there is only one object instance of `class A` (`objA`) each executing thread will have its own value for the thread local variable `student` according to ThreadLocal javadoc,

> These variables differ from their normal counterparts in that each
>   thread that accesses one (via its {@code get} or {@code set} method)
>   has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable

Note that in here you have used `InheritableThreadLocal` and according to its java doc

> This class extends ThreadLocal to provide inheritance of
>   values  from parent thread to child thread: when a child thread is
>   created, the  child receives initial values for all inheritable
>   thread-local variables  for which the parent has values.

So if you set the thread local value in the parent thread, same value will be available in the child thread. However, you can modify the thread local value in the child thread, but it will not affect the thread local value of the parent thread.

Be careful when using thread locals. If you are using a thread pool, it is a must to clean thread locals at the correct time. Otherwise thread local leaks will occur.

Comment: Pay close attention to what @Sajith said also in his last sentence. If this code is running on a web server they pretty much ALL are using a threadpool, so your threadlocal will contain the value that the last random request had happened to leave behind. The solution to that is have a ServletFilter, which specifically resets the threalocal var to null upon exit inside a 'finally' block, to be sure it is ALWAYS called even during exceptions.

Here's an example of a Filter doing this:

https://github.com/Clay-Ferguson/meta64/blob/master/src/main/java/com/meta64/mobile/config/AppFilter.java

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I actually ran in to a situation where i still see some student object set by previous threads in the new thread invocation also. It was happen when using @Async with custom thread pool. I get rid of the thread local for it.